# Why my Jasper soft studio is crashing while connection with database?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I am creating the report in jasper studio. when I am creating static content report in jasper studio its working fine and I am able to connect the database also but when I am trying to run the query as soon as I click the run button then the jasper is crashed suddenly and its happens almost every time. I try to change the heap size also . I am using 6.10 version of jasper soft and trying another version also but same thing happen.

please provide the solution. I am facing this issue from last 3 weeks nd try all possible way nothing can help .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

looking at the error log it appears there are a lot of SWTException when working with a custom widget "SelectableComposite".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).